# What year had the most champions racing in Formula 1?

Tags: formula-1

During 2021, there were 4 champions competing in F1: Hamilton, Vettel, Raikkonen, and Alonso. There are also 4 champions competing in 2022: Hamilton, Vettel, Verstappen, and Alonso. I want to know which year had the most champions competing in Formula 1?

Answer (score 3):

That would be [the 2012 season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Formula_One_World_Championship), which had 6 former world champions on the grid: Sebastian Vettel, Fernando Alonso, Jenson Button, Lewis Hamilton, Kimi Raikkonen, and Michael Schumacher.

There were 5 world champions on the grid in 2011 (all of the above except Raikkonen), and again from 2013 to 2016 (all of the above except Schumacher). The only other time this has happened was the 1970 Mexican Grand Prix (Jackie Stewart, Jack Brabham, Graham Hill, Denny Hulme, John Surtees).